# Don't understand what's wrong with my date generation

Tags: objective-c, date

I can't understand why I keep getting strange results when trying to build a date from NSDateComponents and NSCalendar :

As proven in the console results below, the date components seems to be ok but not the generated date. Does someone has an answer ?

Code :

```
NSCalendar* l_currentCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] ;
NSDateComponents* dc = [l_currentCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:[NSDate Date]];
[dc setDay:1];
NSDate* l_startOfThisMonth = [l_currentCalendar dateFromComponents:dc];
NSLog(@"startOfThisMonth : %@ (%d;%d;%d)",l_startOfThisMonth,[dc year],[dc month],[dc day]);
```

Console output:

```
2016-07-04 17:14:46.782 [832:32959] startOfThisMonth : 2016-06-30 22:00:00 +0000 (2016;7;1)
```

Comment: Are you currently at UTC+2? If yes, then it's the same date.

Comment: @Larme Indeed I am at UTC+2 (in summer only ; UTC+1 in winter) !... 
I am amazed you fond that so fast lol. I've never worked yet with time zones. Do you have some clue to where to start to get my first date and last date of the current month then ?

Comment: `NSLog` prints `NSDate` objects in UTC. The dates `2016-06-30 22:00:00 +0000` and `2016-07-01 00:00:00 +0200` are the same.

Comment: @vadian Thanks. You're right, that seems the clue. I now have to figure out how to correctly set the time zone to get 2016-07-01 00:00:00

Comment: Rather than `NSLog` use `NSDateFormatter`. It considers the current time zone by default.

Comment: @vadian Oh ! I understand now, lol. You're saying that my **l_startOfThisMonth date variable is already correct**... Only its printing value seems incorrect to me. Ok, thanks a lot... I'll keep that in mind starting from now. That means that the both of you have "solved" my problem. Thanks.

Comment: By the way: The *state of the art* way to get the first day of the current month is `NSDate *startDate;` `[calendar rangeOfUnit:NSCalendarUnitMonth startDate: &startDate interval: nil forDate: [NSDate date]];` The result is in `startDate`.